# How to show timer in days after 24H using C# Timer

Tags: c#, timer

I've used System.Threading.Timer in my project like code below:

```
async Task Timer()
{
    timer = new System.Threading.Timer((_) =>
    {
        TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now.Subtract(ed);
        Time = (TimeSpan.FromTicks(span.Ticks).ToString()).Substring(0, 8);
        InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }, null, 0, 1000);
}
```

how should I change it to show timer in days, after 24h?
Thanks in advance

Comment: 1000 milliseconds = 1 second. 1 day = 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds = 86400000 milliseconds. [Docs for the constructor you're using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Timer__ctor_System_Threading_TimerCallback_System_Object_System_Int64_System_Int64_).

Comment: `Every thing works fine until it is not still 24H.` And then what happens? How _specifically_ is it not working?

Comment: Tell us what `.Substring(0, 8);` is trying to achieve.

Comment: @mjwills after it passes 24H the timer does not show meaning full context. and the substring part just takes the time part and omits date

Comment: Timespans don't ever contain a *date* by the way

Comment: I don't see the point of your method being a `async Task Timer()`. It's not doing any awaits.

Comment: I'd use Rx, btw. Then you could do this `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromDays(1.2)).Subscribe(x => { /* Do stuff */ });`.

Comment: I understood that the code I've used is working correctly and it calculates days too. Just the way it show made me confused. Thanks every one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timespans roll up to days level, they don't stop at counting hours. If you have a timespan that represents *23:59:59* and you add a second to it, you do not get *24:00:00* you get *1 day 00:00:00*

If you want it to count in hours forever you'll have to multiply the days back to hours yourself

```
$"{t.Days*24+t.Hours}:{t.Minutes}:{t.Seconds}"
```

You could also cut the decimal part off the total hours

```
$"{(int)t.TotalHours}:{t.Minutes}:{t.Seconds}"

$"{t.TotalHours:F0}:{t.Minutes}:{t.Seconds}"
```